# Pandas reindexing timerange special way with ffill()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, merge

Here is my question:

1. I have input data like this column(UNIX)

   time
   1577919600
   1577923200
   1577926800
   1577930400
   1577934000
   1577941200
2. I convert it to UTC_0 Time and get this:

   ```
   UTC_0                time
   01.01.2020  23:00:00 1577919600
   02.01.2020  00:00:00 1577923200
   02.01.2020  01:00:00 1577926800
   02.01.2020  02:00:00 1577930400
   02.01.2020  03:00:00 1577934000
   02.01.2020  05:00:00 1577941200
   ```
3. We can see here 1h step, but it can be 15 min, or 1D or etc.

You can also see the gap from 3 to 5 hours

I want it to convert to 5 min step where I use

```
`pd.date_range(df['UTC_0'].iloc[0], df['UTC_0'].iloc[-1], freq=f"{timeframe}" + "min")`
and
`df.reindex(timrange, fill_value=np.NAN)`
```

I get the expected result:

```
UTC_0                time
02.01.2020  03:55:00
02.01.2020  04:00:00 
02.01.2020  04:05:00
...
02.01.2020  04:55:00
02.01.2020  05:00:00 1577941200
02.01.2020  05:05:00
```

The thing i need is to ffill 'time' data according to extended index, but only where the 'time' was before reindexing, and left NaN where was no 'time'(like on this example maken manually).

```
    UTC_0                time
    02.01.2020  03:55:00 1577934000
    02.01.2020  04:00:00 NaN
    02.01.2020  04:05:00 NaN
    ...
    02.01.2020  04:55:00 NaN
    02.01.2020  05:00:00 1577941200
    02.01.2020  05:05:00 1577941200
```

The result must be like this - filled extended 'time' column only there were value and left NaN where were no 'time'.

Maybe there is more proprly way to extend Date indext to 5 min with ffill gaps, but left that gaps in 'time' column and ffill only extended to 5 min step rangies of rows.

Thank You all!

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1re77qp8bu8i484k2lYlqgADnTia-nK-b/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107298604225579447934&rtpof=true&sd=true
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQ8bpnW6eLXU1bMRbAOXFnrcphoYWySV/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107298604225579447934&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Kindly provide a small input dataframe, with the expected output dataframe. Right now, we are having to guess the input and output which isn't helpful

Comment: Thank for a piece of advice! I've added the input / output data and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "UTC_0": [
            "01.01.2020 23:00:00",
            "02.01.2020 00:00:00",
            "02.01.2020 01:00:00",
            "02.01.2020 03:00:00",
            "02.01.2020 04:00:00",
        ],
        "time": [
            1577919600,
            1577923200,
            1577926800,
            1577934000,
            1577937600,
        ],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
                 UTC_0        time
0  01.01.2020 23:00:00  1577919600
1  02.01.2020 00:00:00  1577923200
2  02.01.2020 01:00:00  1577926800
3  02.01.2020 03:00:00  1577934000
4  02.01.2020 04:00:00  1577937600
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
df["UTC_0"] = pd.to_datetime(df["UTC_0"], format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
range_5min = pd.date_range(df["UTC_0"].iloc[0], df["UTC_0"].iloc[-1], freq="5min")
range_1hour = pd.date_range(df["UTC_0"].iloc[0], df["UTC_0"].iloc[-1], freq="1H")
df = df.set_index("UTC_0")

new_df = df.reindex(range_5min, fill_value=pd.NA)
dfs = [
    new_df.loc[idx : idx + pd.Timedelta(59, "m"), :].ffill()
    if idx in new_df.index
    else new_df.loc[idx : idx + pd.Timedelta(59, "m"), :]
    for idx in range_1hour
]
new_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

                          time
2020-01-01 23:00:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:05:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:10:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:15:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:20:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:25:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:30:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:35:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:40:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:45:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:50:00 1577919600
2020-01-01 23:55:00 1577919600
2020-01-02 00:00:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:05:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:10:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:15:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:20:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:25:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:30:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:35:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:40:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:45:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:50:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 00:55:00 1577923200
2020-01-02 01:00:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:05:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:10:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:15:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:20:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:25:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:30:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:35:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:40:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:45:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:50:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 01:55:00 1577926800
2020-01-02 02:00:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:05:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:10:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:15:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:20:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:25:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:30:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:35:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:40:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:45:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:50:00        NaN
2020-01-02 02:55:00        NaN
2020-01-02 03:00:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:05:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:10:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:15:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:20:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:25:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:30:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:35:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:40:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:45:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:50:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 03:55:00 1577934000
2020-01-02 04:00:00 1577937600
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank You for the ansver.
1. This is good solution.
2. It gave me a new solution:

Reindex to original timestep, as You did

range_1hour = pd.date_range(df["UTC_0"].iloc[0], df["UTC_0"].iloc[-1], freq="1H")
df = df.reindex(range_1hour , fill_value=pd.NA)
ffill NaN with any value in original step
df.fillna(value=0)

reindex again, but to 5 min 

range_5min = pd.date_range(df["UTC_0"].iloc[0], df["UTC_0"].iloc[-1], freq="5min")
df = df.reindex(range_5min, fill_value=pd.NA)

and it is possible to use simple ffill() as now we have 0 in 1H original timestamp row
df.ffill()